# ec2 convert instance to reserved instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an existing ec2 instance ( m1.small ). Based on a question here, I bought a reserved instance in same zone and same type. The note here ( and in amazon groups ) had mentioned that my existing instance automatically gets converted to use the reserved instance ( lower costs ). Is there a way to verify this - say from the aws management console ?

Thanks

pady

Answer (score 4):

The reservation isn't for any particular instance (which is why it happens automatically).  The best you can do I suspect is to have a look at the account page of your AWS account, and see whether the charges have been applied, and paid on your credit card.

Answer (score 1):

The management console shows if a reserved instance is in use. Note that it must be in the same availability zone.

And you see it on your bill: http://aws.typepad.com/files/ec2_ri_jeffbarr_account.gif

Comment: I am not sure where i see "management console shows if a reserved instance is in use".

Answer (score 0):

You can see if its being billed correctly by the instance price that you're paying for each hour. You can see this in AWS Billing Console, Bills.
Its detailed by service.